# bat file: get parent pathname

Tags: cmd, batch-file, pathname

The following mostly works. 'Mostly', because the use of the SOMETHING..\tasks\ pathname confuses Spring when a context XML file tries to include another by relative pathname. So, what I seem to need is a way, in a BAT file, of setting a variable to the parent directory of a pathname.

```
set ROOT=%~dp0
java -Xmx1g -jar %ROOT%\..\lib\ajar.jar %ROOT%\..\tasks\fas-model.xml tasks
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To resolve a relative path name you can utilize a sub routine call.
At the end of your batch file place the following lines:

```
GOTO :EOF

:RESOLVE
SET %2=%~f1 
GOTO :EOF
```

This is a sub routine that resolves its first parameter to a full path (`%~f1`) and stores the result to the (global) variable named by the 2nd parameter

You can use the routine like this:

```
CALL :RESOLVE "%ROOT%\.." PARENT_ROOT
```

After the call you can use the variable `%PARENT_ROOT%` that contains the parent path name contained in the `%ROOT%` variable.

Your complete batch file should look like this:

```
SET ROOT=%~dp0

CALL :RESOLVE "%ROOT%\.." PARENT_ROOT

java -Xmx1g -jar "%PARENT_ROOT%\lib\ajar.jar" "%PARENT_ROOT%\tasks\fas-model.xml" tasks

GOTO :EOF

:RESOLVE
SET %2=%~f1 
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Hm, nice idea. I'd have abused `pushd`, `popd` and `%CD%` but this one is more elegant, actually.

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks, I also thought about `pushd` and `popd`, but i didn't remember the `%CD%` variable any more. So this way was more obvious to me.

Comment: Paraphrasing Perl: *»Batch files: There's more than one way to do it«* ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a one liner

```
for %%A in ("%~dp0\..") do set "root_parent=%%~fA"
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2172378/1037948), if you want to keep marching up the path (to get the parent's parent directory, for example), strip the trailing slash:

```
:PARENT_PATH
:: use temp variable to hold the path, so we can substring
SET PARENT_PATH=%~dp1
:: strip the trailing slash, so we can call it again to get its parent
SET %2=%PARENT_PATH:~0,-1%
GOTO :EOF
```

Usage:

```
CALL :PARENT_PATH "%~dp0" PARENT_ROOT
CALL :PARENT_PATH "%PARENT_ROOT%" PARENT_ROOT
echo Parent Root is: %PARENT_ROOT%
```

would yield `C:\My\Path` from `C:\My\Path\Child\file.bat`.

If I understood it better, I'd suggest a "wrapper function" so you could `CALL :REMOVE_SEGMENTS %path% 3 PARENT` to strip the last 3 segments from `%path%`.